# Capturing code between two tags in Flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer

```
[/][*][^*]*[*]+([^*/][^*]*[*]+)*[/]
```

This is what I got from a different post on stack overflow. I can't seem to find a way to make it work with "#" instead of "/*" and "*/"

Comment: FYI, the `flex` tag refers to Apache Flex.  For the CSS `flex` property use the tag flexbox instead.  As for your question, you might include a link to the other question and explain in more detail how this is different...

Answer (score 0):

With a single character, the pattern is much simpler: a `#`, a sequence of any length not containing `#`, and another `#`:

```
"#"[^#]*"#"
```